# Swift Trouble with using the Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue, navigationbar

I am trying to add a Back button onto my table view controller (far right VC in the picture). I embeded a Navigation Controller and added a Back Item on the navigation bar with a segue to my second VC. However when I run the code, after I press back on the TableVC, it goes to a blank screen with the Back button still at the top. I want to be able to have the second VC screen when the back button is clicked, but I think there is some funky thing the navigation bar does. I was wondering if there was a way around this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I'm pretty sure your problem is your embedding the wrong controller in the nav controller. You want to embed the second view controller in your picture into the nav controller, and then have your last one segue from that view controller.

Also, with a nav controller you don't need to add a nav bar or the back button. The embedded controllers will have these by default.

Embedding controllers is kinda confusing at first so its a good idea to take a look at some additional docs.

Here's a good tutorial that I used when starting out: [Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson8.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Embedding the navigation controller on the second VC did the trick. There is one caveat - when I hit back, it keeps the Back button with a navigation bar on the first VC. Is there a way to get rid of this? Or is it a result of using the embedded navigation bar?

Comment: Did you delete the navigation bar in the first view controller?